# {ENTER} Keystroke iMacros for Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I've found a decent amount of code to replicate a backspace or the enter key (DS, WINCLICK, etc.) -- but none of them work on iMacros for Firefox (Version 8.3.0). Is there anything I can do with this version?

My code is perfect, I just need an 'enter' keystroke or even a backspace after one of the lines to make the dropdown I need populate.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use Experimental recording and click on the place you want to type. Then press Enter.

http://prntscr.com/13dnw9

You can also check and un acheck  the Favor element IDs ... option do get different ways of recording an EVENT command.